# Angular Material - Datepicker moves off bounds

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I'm using Angular 4 with Material 2

[image]

I have an input with a button that opens a date picker

[image]

I use flex-layout to push the button to the right side of the screen, like that:

```
<div fxFlex>

      <span fxFlex></span>

      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="Search in Date" [mdDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
        <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="myDatepicker"></button>
      </md-input-container>
      <md-datepicker #myDatepicker></md-datepicker>
    </div>
```

The problem is that whenever the date picker is opened, part of it hides off the bounds of the window

[image]

And there is no way to scroll right...

How can i get around it?

Comment: this problem is not easily simulatable , can you please provide a plunker for it ?

Comment: It's working fine in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VwCnSuRcLDI2vDZXgRhB?p=preview). Try to reproduce the problem in plunker and share the link.

Comment: @Nehal i wasn't able to reproduce it, only in my own code base i'm able to. I even tried to copy my entire css to your plunker and it worked just fine.. Maybe it has something to do with the versions of material or flex

Comment: @Nehal I just updated @angular/material to the latest version (2.0.0-beta.7) and it works fine now, the calendar button also grew in size which is nice.. I guess it was a real problem until the latest version and now they fixed it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the latest @angular/material version
From 2.0.0-beta.6 to 2.0.0-beta.7 and it works fine now.
I guess that it was a bug that they fixed in the latest version.